# How do I properly align using String.format in Java?

Tags: java, formatting

Let's say I have a couple variable and I want to format them so they're all aligned, but the variables are different lengths. For example:

```
String a = "abcdef";
String b = "abcdefhijk";
```

And I also have a price.

```
double price = 4.56;
```

How would I be able to format it so no matter how long the String is, they are aligned either way?

```
System.out.format("%5s %10.2f", a, price);
System.out.format("%5s %10.2f", b, price);
```

For example, the code above would output something like this:

```
abcdef       4.56
abcdefhijk       4.56
```

But I want it to output something like this:

```
abcdef      4.56
abcdefhijk  4.56
```

How would I go about doing so? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

Use fixed size format:

> Using format strings with fixed size permits to print the strings in a
>   table-like appearance with fixed size columns:
>
> ```
> String rowsStrings[] = new String[] {"1", 
>                                      "1234", 
>                                      "1234567", 
>                                      "123456789"};
>
> String column1Format = "%-3.3s";  // fixed size 3 characters, left aligned
> String column2Format = "%-8.8s";  // fixed size 8 characters, left aligned
> String column3Format = "%6.6s";   // fixed size 6 characters, right aligned
> String formatInfo = column1Format + " " + column2Format + " " + column3Format;
>
> for(int i = 0; i < rowsStrings.length; i++) {
>     System.out.format(formatInfo, rowsStrings[i], rowsStrings[i], rowsStrings[i]);
>     System.out.println();
> }
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> 1   1             1
> 123 1234       1234
> 123 1234567  123456
> 123 12345678 123456
> ```

In your case you could find the maximum length of the strings you want to display and use that to create the appropriate format information, for example:

```
// find the max length
int maxLength = Math.max(a.length(), b.length());

// add some space to separate the columns
int column1Length = maxLength + 2;

// compose the fixed size format for the first column
String column1Format = "%-" + column1Length + "." + column1Length + "s";

// second column format
String column2Format = "%10.2f";

// compose the complete format information
String formatInfo = column1Format + " " + column2Format;

System.out.format(formatInfo, a, price);
System.out.println();
System.out.format(formatInfo, b, price);
```

Comment: I think OP is asking when the maximum length of `a` and `b` are unknown.

Comment: @LorisSecuro Hmm. Interesting. I guess I could do this, only problem is we haven't learned about this in class at all so I'm not sure if I'm allowed to use it. Was looking for a way to do it solely using String.format() but I guess there isn't a way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: @blyter my answer is using the same methods you used in your question, it doesn't really add new concepts.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch added an example to find and use the maximum length

Answer (score 1):

Put negative sign in front of your format specifier so instead of printing 5 spaces to the left of your float value, it adjusts the space on the right until you find the ideal position. It should be fine

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it as below-

```
    String a = "abcdef";
    String b = "abcdefhijk";
    double price = 4.56;

    System.out.println(String.format("%-10s %-10.2f", a, price));
    System.out.println(String.format("%-10s %-10.2f", b, price));
```

output:

```
   abcdef     4.56      
   abcdefhijk 4.56
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the longest `String`, and then use Apache commons-lang [`StringUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) to `leftPad` both of your `String`(s). Something like,

```
int len = Math.max(a.length(), b.length()) + 2;
a = StringUtils.leftPad(a, len);
b = StringUtils.leftPad(b, len);
```

Or, if you can't use `StringUtils` - you could implement `leftPad`. First a method to generate `String` of whitespace. Something like,

```
private static String genString(int len) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        sb.append(' ');
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Then use it to implement `leftPad` - like,

```
private static String leftPad(String in, int len) {
    return new StringBuilder(in) //
            .append(genString(len - in.length() - 1)).toString();
}
```

And, I tested it like,

```
int len = Math.max(a.length(), b.length()) + 2;
System.out.format("%s %.2f%n", leftPad(a, len), price);
System.out.format("%s %.2f%n", leftPad(b, len), price);
```

Which outputs (as I think you wanted)

```
abcdef      4.56
abcdefhijk  4.56
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private String addEnoughSpacesInBetween(String firstStr, String secondStr){

    if (!firstStr.isEmpty() && !secondStr.isEmpty()){

        String space = " ";

        int totalAllowed = 55;

        int multiplyFor = totalAllowed - (firstStr.length() + secondStr.length());

        return StringUtils.repeat(space,multiplyFor);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You should add some explanation.