# How do make it so my println outlines/tabs the way I want in this for loop with multiple lines to print?

Tags: java, printf, text-formatting

So, I've been frollicking around with this for a while and encountered things like using Format and /t and what not. But I still cant figure out how to properly outline the output of my println made by this for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < AANTAL_CIJFERS; i++) //Toon cijfers per vak
    {
        System.out.println("Vak/project:\t" + vakken[i] + "\tCijfer\t: " + cijfers[i] + "\tBehaalde punten: " + puntBehaald(i));
    }
```

It currently prints like this: 
[image]

But i'd like the printline to look more like this:
[image]

But I just cant figure it out, anybody know how I could accomplish this?

Comment: IIRC, `printf` supports this kind of auto-tab-ing. Found it, see the following duplicate:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing with "\t" (tabs) does not result in aligned columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000810/printing-with-t-tabs-does-not-result-in-aligned-columns)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly align using String.format in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43034015/how-do-i-properly-align-using-string-format-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

On this case you have to use java `System.out.printf()`or `String.format()` methods  instead of `System.out.print()`  or `System.out.println()`

Please read this exmples [how-to-use-formatting-with-printf-correctly-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413020/how-to-use-formatting-with-printf-correctly-in-java) and  [tabs-does-not-result-in-aligned-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000810/printing-with-t-tabs-does-not-result-in-aligned-columns) for more details.

Also here is a helpful article [java-string-format-examples](https://dzone.com/articles/java-string-format-examples)

I just update the code to be as the following and it works fine with me :

```
 private static String format = "%s %-30s  ";
private static String format2 = "%s %3s  ";
 . 
 .

    for (int i = 0; i < AANTAL_CIJFERS; i++) //Toon cijfers per vak
    {
        System.out.printf(format, "Vak/project: ", vakken[i]);
        System.out.printf(format2, "Cijfer: ", cijfers[i]);
        System.out.printf(format2, "Behaalde punten: ", puntBehaald(i));
         System.out.printf("%n");
    }
```

Comment: Please see my new ''anwser" for what i've tried with the documentation.

Comment: How should I go about sending you the program to see if you can figure anything out?

Comment: You should use "%n" for eol to be more system agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

So I am now using this as code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < AANTAL_CIJFERS; i++) //Toon cijfers per vak
    {
        System.out.printf(format, "Vak/project: ", vakken[i]);
        System.out.printf(format, "Cijfer: ", cijfers[i]);
        System.out.printf(format, "Behaalde punten: ", puntBehaald(i));
        System.out.printf("\n");
    }
```

Which gives this:
[image]

So it clearly doesnt work the way I'd expect it to from the documentation. What am I doing wrong?
It should be: Vak/project: "output from vakken[i]" TAB Cijfer: "output from cijfers[i]" TAB Behaalde punten: "output from puntBehaald(i)".

This is my format right now: `private static String format = "%-20s%s";`

Comment: try to use longest format for the second one, for exmple private static String format2 = "%-40s%s";

Comment: The ''cijfer'' part keeps being stuck to the vakken[i] output, even now that the second print uses your format and the first one uses my basic one.

Comment: can you please provide the data, so I can try it locally

Comment: Check my latest edit, I hope this clears up the issue.

Comment: I'd send you the file for the program but I wouldnt know how to

Comment: I just update my answer and used     private static String format = "%s %-30s  ";
    private static String format2 = "%s %3s  ";, please let me know if that  work fine with you